# Is this a scam?

Tags: scam

Hey there I almost put a etherium into this so called bot that makes money of swaps or something. It seemed good like it was klegit but I am seeing other people saying they were scammed by a similar opportunity. Here is the link with the video and step by step instructions. Thanks for your time !

https://telegra.ph/Blog-Easy-to-Use-Arbitrage-Uniswap-Bot-01-20

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a scam, do not deposit money.